# UWP Lumia VB.Net Video effect

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

I need help to apply a Lumia 3.0 SDK effect (Vignette) to webcam live video. 
My webcam / video is ready and running.
I have tried to translate the example from Microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/Lumia-imaging-sdk/tree/master/Samples/VideoEffectSample
 to VB without success.
I am using VB but a very simple C# example would also be welcome.
I am relatively new in UWP environment.

In advance thank you for any help

Comment: So could you describe the effect you want more clearly with more details or a image to clarify it?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply.
I would like to understand how to implement all the Lumia SDK effects to my webcam video, but the one effect I am searching to apply to my video is vignette. I dont know how to add a picture here, but if you use the link you can see it https://www.anapnoes.gr/i-pio-xigimeni-syngnomi-ine-i-allagi-syberiforas/
A simple example would help